# reading .txt file in c to lines

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read a .txt file to char arrays with a while loop:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
```

the problem is that every-time the condition of the loop is checked the cursor is moved to the next line, meaning that a line is missed. Is there another condition I can use or a way to stop fgets from moving the cursor?

Comment: Maybe `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) && *line != '\n')`? Can't say more without you presenting a [mcve]

Comment: It's not missed, it's saved into `line`. are you calling `fgets`again inside the loop?

Comment: @IlBeldus Yes, that was the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))` does not move the cursor.  It is other unposted code that is the issue - likely the `'\n'` in `line[]` getting printed.